# Transferring docker image including cache to another host

Tags: docker, caching

Working with a locally built docker image, no remote registry, how can I transfer it with its build cache to another host, ideally integrating cache into the image?

Currently I build via the inline cache method
https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/backends/inline/

```
docker buildx build --cache-to type=inline --cache-from type=registry,ref=<image> .
```

then do docker save then docker load (onto transferred host), but it then wants to rebuild from scratch.  It doesn't help to make a new container from the image, commit and save it either.

This container takes a lot of work to build adjusting to downloaded package updates etc when starting from scratch so I want to avoid future full rebuilds when I can.